# If $Var[X]$ is much larger than $E[X]^2$ is E[X] an unreliable estimate?

Tags: variance, mean

My question is simple and I got this confusion when going through a Markov chains text book.If $Var[X]$ is much larger than $E[X]^2$ is $E[X]$ an unreliable estimate?

Comment: Hint: what happens when $E(x)=0$?

Comment: Can you point to a situation where you think it occurs?

Comment: @mpiktas Please check what you wrote: it appears to assert that the variance is always zero. Are you perhaps interpreting "$E[X]^2$" as $E[X^2]$? (As written in the question, the brackets leave no doubt: $E[X]^2$ means $(E[X])^2$.)

Comment: I note that the original used $\text{Var}(x)$ vs $E(X^2)$. Was the implied distinction between sample and population deliberate?

Comment: $E[X]$ is not an estimate/estimator, it is the theoretical expected value, the "population mean". If you meant to ask about "sample mean - $\bar X$" please clarify so, and also clarify whether all the other expected values appearing are to be understood as sample estimates of the population analogues, or whether it is assumed that we are given as a fact this "large difference". Finally, the comments reveal a doubt of whether you meant $E(X^2)$ or $[E(X)]^2$.

Comment: Ok, I got the parenthesis mixed. I've deleted the comment.